# Is pressure the effect of an internal force in context with fluids

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

> In fluids, in the state of equilibrium, there can only appear internal normal forces and these forces always have a tendency to compress the bounded volume in the fluid.
> Cited - Physics Galaxy ( Ashish Arora )

Would it be apt to say that in context with fluids, if I drop a block, the pressure exerted by the fluid on the block will be the effect of a compressive internal normal force over an area ?

In addition, why is pressure independent of the amount of fluid above it, since it is the weight of the fluid that is causing the compressive force to act?

***What i think:***

Maybe somehow Pascal's principal acts on this, equalizing the forces and leading to pressure equalizing at all heights irrespective of the shape of the tube, if I'm right, could you elaborate on how it actually happens?

[image]

Comment: Would be nice if someone could help me out on this one ?